# adding id field to HTML end result of a GSP <g:form> tag

Tags: html, grails, gsp

Im creating a GSP form that i wish to submit using the $.ajax() call.

I understand that the GSPs get rendered into the final HTML that is seen by the browser, and thus javascript can call normal HTML elements.

my form is created as such:

```
<g:form action="save" id="callmeForm" >
  <fieldset class="form">
    <g:render template="form"/>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="buttons">
    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
  </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

but when the final form is rendered in HTML, it lacks the id field i gave in the  tag:

```
<form action="/racetrack/callback/save/callmeForm" method="post" >
  <fieldset class="form">
    etc...
```

Is there a way I can get the id property to carry thru so i can reference the form by its id with javascript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [*name*](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/form.html) attribute which sets both the form tag's *name* and *id* attributes to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax to post back to the server, why not just go with:

```
<form id="callmeForm">
```

instead?

What does using the gsp tag buy you in this case?

Or, you could try g:formRemote, which has some interesting built-in features:
http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/adding-javascript-validation-to-formremote-ajax-forms-in-grails/